# How to catch in a list several element's content with selenium's find_elements_by_xpath?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, format

Currently I am extracting some content from the web with selenium as follows:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('website.com')
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('''.//*[@id='section-1']//td[1]//a[2]''')
links = [x.get_attribute('href') for x in links]

lis = list()
print(lis)
```

Then I print a nested list with the content:

```
[["Our culture has gotten too mean and too rough, especially to children and teenagers," she said. "It is never OK when a 12-year-old girl or boy is mocked, bullied or attacked" in the school yard, she argued, but it is "absolutely unacceptable when it is done by someone with no name hiding on the internet."], [Delivering a get-out-the-vote speech in the Philadelphia suburbs on Thursday, Melania Trump pledged to focus on combating online bullying and campaigning for women and children if her husband is elected to the White House.], ["We have to find a better way to talk to each other, to disagree with each other, to respect each other," she said.], [Thursday's speech was Melania Trump's first since she addressed the Republican National Convention in July. That speech was well-received initially, but was quickly overshadowed by the discovery that sections had been plagiarised from First Lady Michelle Obama's address to the 2008 Democratic National Convention.], [An average of polls compiled by the RealClearPolitics website gave her a lead of 1.7 percentage points on Thursday, well down from the solid advantage she had until late last month.]]
```

My main objective is to add several xpaths with more content to each list with more than one xpath, something like this:

```
[[<here_goes_more_content_extracted_from_the_site>|"Our culture has gotten too mean and too rough, especially to children and teenagers," she said. "It is never OK when a 12-year-old girl or boy is mocked, bullied or attacked" in the school yard, she argued, but it is "absolutely unacceptable when it is done by someone with no name hiding on the internet."], [<here_goes_more_content_extracted_from_the_site>|Delivering a get-out-the-vote speech in the Philadelphia suburbs on Thursday, Melania Trump pledged to focus on combating online bullying and campaigning for women and children if her husband is elected to the White House.], [<here_goes_more_content_extracted_from_the_site>|"We have to find a better way to talk to each other, to disagree with each other, to respect each other," she said.], [<here_goes_more_content_extracted_from_the_site>|Thursday's speech was Melania Trump's first since she addressed the Republican National Convention in July. That speech was well-received initially, but was quickly overshadowed by the discovery that sections had been plagiarised from First Lady Michelle Obama's address to the 2008 Democratic National Convention.], [<here_goes_more_content_extracted_from_the_site>|An average of polls compiled by the RealClearPolitics website gave her a lead of 1.7 percentage points on Thursday, well down from the solid advantage she had until late last month.]]
```

In addition I am curious if there is any way to pass to `find_elements_by_xpath()` function a list or a sequence of xpaths to retrive:

```
content = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(['.//*[@id="accordion"]','.//*[@id="accordion2"],...,'.//*[@id="accordion"]']).
content = [x.text for x in content]
```

So, how to create a list conformed with several xpath elements separated by something like a: `|` or another character?.

Answer (score 1):

> *So, how to create a list conformed with several xpath elements separated by something like a: `|` or another character?.*

You can do exactly that. `|` is union operator in XPath. Passing multiple XPath expression separated by `|` would return elements matched by at least on of the XPath, in a single list, in document order :

```
xpath = ".//foo|.//bar|.//baz" 
content = [e.text for e in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)]
# the result would be something like :
# [<foo ../>,<bar ../>,<baz ../>,<bar ../>]
```

If you want the result of each XPath to be in a separate list, then you don't need `|` :

```
xpath_list = [".//foo", ".//bar", ".//baz"]
content = [[e.text for e in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)] \
           for xpath in xpath_list]
# the result would be something like :
# [[<foo ../>],[<bar ../>,<bar ../>],[<baz ../>]]
```